# Why is Github desktop creating a new folder rather than using the one I specified when creating a new local repo?

Tags: version-control, github-desktop

I am looking to do something I thought was pretty simple... I have an existing folder (with project files) on my desktop that I would like have tracked by Github desktop for purposes of source/version control. It seems straightforward... I go to github desktop, select that I'd like to create a new repository, and point it at the folder on the desktop. Here is what I expect to happen:

- Desktop

  - Project folder

    - Project files
    - (hidden) .git folder
    - (hidden) .gitattributes

Instead, this is what I get:

- Desktop

  - Project folder

    - Project files
    - New folder with specified git repo name

      - (hidden) .git folder
      - (hidden) .gitattributes

I am not sure why this is happening and it is very frustrating. It looks to me like I have only two options here:

1. Cut and paste `Project files` into `New folder with specified git repo name`
2. Cut and paste `.git folder` and `.gitattributes` out of `New folder with specified git repo name` and into `Project folder`, delete `New folder with specified git repo name`, remove the new repo in Github Desktop when it says it can't find it, and "Add Existing repo" in Github Desktop and point it at `Project folder`.

Both of these approaches sort of feel like hacks and I am not sure what consequences, if any, may negatively impact my version control intention as a result. Is this a common problem? What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use github desktop to make your repository. If you don't have it already try installing git bash, a command line interface, and initialize git from there.

1. Find your existing folder and move to it using `cd <folder name here>` if you go into the wrong place use `cd ..` to move out/back one folder
2. When in your folder use `git init` to initialize git(the version control software)
3. Open GitHub Desktop once again and hit "add" then "add existing repository" finally "choose" and find your file in your file explorer

Answer (score 1):

When you go to "Create a new repository":

- Name: `New folder with specified git repo name`
- Local Path: `Desktop` (ie one level up from `Project files`)

This will create the `.git` and `.gitattributes` in your existing folder without affecting the other files.

The Create a new repository dialogue seems to assume the name should be used as a new folder under the path you specify.

Note that if there are spaces in your name, it tries to replace them with hyphens.

Comment: I don't understand how this would conceptually work... I'm only pointing at desktop? I have other folders on my desktop too that I wouldn't want to have as part of the git repo.

Comment: It's creating a folder for a git repo on your Desktop with the name you specify.  If the folder from Name already exists, then whatever is already in there gets put into the repo.